# Complex object dynamic form creation with Angular Reactive Forms

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a products object as mentioned below from which I have to create a complex form

**component.ts**

```typescript
    import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
    @Component({
      selector: "my-app",
      templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
      styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      products = [
        {
          Id: 1,
          Name: "productA",
          referralCode: "codeA",
          webUrl: "https://productA.com",
          allowReferralCode: true
        },
        {
          Id: 2,
          Name: "productb",
          referralCode: null,
          webUrl: "https://productb.com",
          allowReferralCode: true
        },
        {
          Id: 3,
          Name: "productC",
          referralCode: null,
          webUrl: "https://productC.com",
          allowReferralCode: false
        }
      ];
      productForm: FormGroup;
    
      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.productForm = this.fb.group({
          products: new FormArray([])
        });
    
        this.products.forEach(item => {
          if (item.referralCode !== null && item.allowReferralCode) {
            this.t.push(
              this.fb.group({
                productId: [""],
                referralCode: [""],
                link: [""]
              })
            );
          } else if (item.allowReferralCode) {
            this.t.push(
              this.fb.group({
                productId: [""],
                referralCode: [""]
              })
            );
          } else if (!item.allowReferralCode) {
            this.t.push(
              this.fb.group({
                productId: [""],
                link: [""]
              })
            );
          }
        });
      }
    
      get f() {
        return this.productForm.controls;
      }
      get t() {
        return this.f.products as FormArray;
      }
      get productsFormGroups() {
        return this.t.controls as FormGroup[];
      }
    
      onSubmit(form) {
        alert(
          "SUCCESS!! :-)\n\n" + JSON.stringify(this.productForm.value, null, 4)
        );
      }
    }
```

Below is the HTML:

```html
    component.html
    <form [formGroup]="productForm" (submit)="onSubmit(productForm)">
      <div *ngFor="let product of products">
        <div
          *ngIf="product.referralCode !== null && product.allowReferralCode; else showWithReferalCode"
        >
          <div class="card ml-3 mt-3 mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
            <h4 class="mb-0 ml-3">{{product.Name | titlecase}}</h4>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="new-custom-radio ml-2 mb-3">
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    id="customRadio1"
                    name="customRadio"
                    class="custom-control-input"
                  />
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio1"
                    >I have a Referral Code</label
                  >
                </div>
                <div class="referral-code-input">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="new-custom-radio ml-2 mb-3">
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    id="customRadio2"
                    name="customRadio"
                    class="custom-control-input"
                  />
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadio2"
                    >I have a Custom Web Link</label
                  >
                </div>
    
                <div class="referral-code-input">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ng-template #showWithReferalCode>
          <div *ngIf="product.allowReferralCode; else showWebUrl">
            <div class="card ml-3 mt-3 mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
              <h4 class="mb-0 ml-3">{{product.Name | titlecase}}</h4>
              <div class="m-3 form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">I have Referral code</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  class="form-control"
                  id="exampleInputEmail1"
                  aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ng-template #showWebUrl>
            <div class="card ml-3 mt-3 mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
              <h4 class="mb-0 ml-3">{{product.Name | titlecase}}</h4>
              <div class="m-3 form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">I have WebUrl</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  class="form-control"
                  id="exampleInputEmail1"
                  aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
        </ng-template>
      </div>
      <div class="mt-2 mb-4 text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

I want to create a dynamic form for some conditions as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Now let me break it down whenever I have a referral code and allowReferralCode=true within my product I need to allow users to choose either referral code or custom code. At the same time if any product doesn't have a referral code and allowReferralCode=true then they will have to ask for a referral code and also if allowReferralCode=false then enter a direct URL.

I'm trying to build a dynamic form with form builder and FormArrays and it seems like as I have conditions in my HTML I'm unable to set form controls of the FormArray to form.

Below is the stack blitz version of the same.

[stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/complex-form-rendering?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Whenever I'm trying to form control name to the inputs I'm getting this kind of error

```
**ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'referralCode'**
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @OwenKelvin yes I was able to figure it out. by using the productsFormGroups method to get the list of form groups of the array and use that as a source for ngFor loop instead of my products object.